# Performance strategies for selecting large amounts of data from child tables

Tags: sql-server

I have a fairly standard database structure for storing invoices and their line items. We have an AccountingDocuments table for header details, and AccountingDocumentItems child table. The child table has a foreign key of AccountingDocumentId with associated non-clustered index.

Most of our Sales reports need to select almost all the columns in the child table, based on a passed date range and branch. So the basic query would be something like:

```
SELECT
    adi.TotalInclusive,
    adi.Description, etc.
FROM
    AccountingDocumentItems adi
LEFT JOIN AccountingDocuments ad on ad.AccountingDocumentId=adi.AccountingDocumentId
WHERE
    ad.DocumentDate > '1 Jan 2022' and ad.DocumentDate < '5 May 2022'
AND
    ad.SiteId='x'
```

This results in an index seek on the AccountingDocuments table, but due to the select requirements on AccountingDocumentItems we're seeing a full index scan here. I'm not certain how to index the child table given the filtering is taking place on the parent table.

At present there are only around 2m rows in the line items table, and the query performs quite well. My concern is how this will work once the table is significantly larger and what strategies there are to ensure good performance on these reports going forward.

I'm aware the answer may be to simply keep adding hardware, but want to investigate alternative strategies to this.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but what's to prevent you from adding indexes to `AccountingDocumentItems`? If this is a query that executes fairly often, and typically pulls the same columns, you can index for those. Viewing the execution plan typically also yields suggested indexes for queries. You can start by using that suggestion if you're unsure how to pick the columns for the index.

Comment: Hi SchmitzIT. I guess my confusion is how do I index the child table. The where clause is based on columns in the parent table. The index on the parent table is being used, but what would I index on the child table to make this query efficient?

Comment: one minor suggestion - your LEFT JOIN is de-facto INNER JOIN

Comment: @Gary - Typically, a good starting point is to check the suggestion from SSMS. Otherwise, another approach is to add any columns used in the `WHERE`, `JOIN`, and `SELECT` part of the query.

Comment: May be it would be interesting to take look on INCLUDE-columns. Something like CREATE INDEX IDX_DocumentItems ON AccountingDocumentItems(AccountingDocumentId) INCLUDE (TotalInclusive,Description)

Comment: @SchmitzIT. Yes, I do understand this, but there are no index suggestions from SSMS - so I don't have any starting point here. Does this mean Sql Server is doing the best it can to get this data?

Comment: @Sergey. Yes, I played around with this option too. Even adding all columns as includes, but still an Index Scan takes place on the primary key of the child table.

Comment: Please share the execution plan via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan. Please also show us your tables and current indexes. This question is not answerable without these.

Comment: I'm guessing the best index here is probably `AccountingDocuments  (SiteId, DocumentDate) INCLUDE (AccountingDocumentId)` although possibly swapping `AccountingDocumentId` and `DocumentDate` might work. The table `AccountingDocumentItems` should be clustered on `AccountingDocumentId` note that the primary key does not have to be the clustering key

Comment: `AccountingDocumentItems adi LEFT JOIN AccountingDocuments a` How could a row in the child table exist without a related row in the Parent? This query suggests schema and coding writing issues. But quite frankly, we don't optimize things that "performs quite well". We do want to monitor the system for problems - but that is a very different question.

Comment: @Sergey. So with some additional tries, it seems the best option is in fact to include the selected columns in the AccountingDocumentId index on the child table. This does result in a Index Seek and massively reduces IO.